# Dummit and Foote 10.1.20

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, vector-spaces, modules, linear-transformations

I am working through some problems about modules in Dummit and Foote, and cannot figure this one out at all: 10.1.20

Let $\mathbb F = \mathbb R$ and let $V = \mathbb R^2$ and let $T$ be the linear transformation from $V$ to $V$ which is rotation clockwise about the origin by $\pi$ radians. Show that every subspace of $V$ is $\mathbb F[x]$-submodule for this $T$.

I just have no clue how to approach this question, and not sure how to prove this.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Half the question is figuring out what it's asking.  When it says $F[x]$ module, it means that multiplying by $x$ is the same as applying $T$.  So, the question is: why is every subspace fixed under both multiplication by scalars (the $F$ part) and rotation by $\pi$ radians (the $[x]$ part)?

Comment: Every subspace is closed under scalar multiplication by definition no? and Isn't rotation by $\pi$ radians, just scalar multiplication of the vector by -1? Thus closed as well? I'm not sure if I'm right about these statements though.

Comment: @user282639 You're correct. Another (geometric) way to think about it is that all nonzero subspaces of $\mathbb R^2$ look like straight lines through the origin. Rotating a straight line about the origin by the angle $\pi$ leaves the line fixed.

Comment: That's good to hear. I'm failing to see the connection between the problem and the statements above though..

Comment: So you know what a module is, right?  It's an abelian group on which the ring acts.  So the subspace $W$ is obviously an abelian group; how does $F[x]$ act?  Well, we know how to multiply by things in $F$; we just need to know how to multiply by $x$.  But this is what $T$ does: $x\cdot v=Tv$ by definition.  So the question is whether this definition makes sense: is $Tv$ still inside $W$?  The answer as you said is obviously yes, so $W$ is an $F[x]$ module.  (It's a submodule of $V$.)

Comment: The question is kind of weird. $T$ has the said property if and only if $T = \lambda \operatorname{id}$ for some scalar $\lambda$...So basically the question is figuring out that rotating by $\pi$ is the same as multiplying by $-1$...